# Ошибка при запуске "Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport"

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-mvc, tomee

При запуске программы на TomEE сервере программа выдает ошибку:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport

Несмотря на то что jar файл(`spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar`), с этим классом, присутствует.

В `WEB-INF/lib foldere` находится следующий список jar файлов:

```
aopalliance-1.0.jar
commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
groovy-2.3.9.jar
groovy-json-2.3.9.jar
groovy-xml-2.3.9.jar
hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
httpclient-4.2.2.jar
httpcore-4.2.2.jar
jackson-annotations-2.5.0.jar
jackson-core-2.5.4.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.9.10.jar
jackson-databind-2.5.4.jar
jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.10.jar
jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.9.jar
jsr311-api-1.0.jar
junit-4.12.jar
soa-model-core-1.5.4.jar
spring-aop-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-asm-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
```

Полный stacktrace здесь:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [cxf.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Invalid NamespaceHandler class [org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spring.NamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws]: problem with handler class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/NamespaceHandlerSupport
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:412)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
.....

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Invalid NamespaceHandler class [org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spring.NamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws]: problem with handler class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/NamespaceHandlerSupport
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.resolve(DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:139)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1333)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1328)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:135)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:93)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
... 76 more

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/NamespaceHandlerSupport
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1709)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.LazyStopWebappClassLoader.loadClass(LazyStopWebappClassLoader.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1573)
at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:257)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.resolve(DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:124)
... 82 more

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 100 more
```

Comment: Вы не туда смотрите. `Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [cxf.xml]` в стектрейсе вам о чем-то говорит?

Comment: Это тот файл который мы парсим,

Answer (score 3):

Выяснилось что не хватало `jar` файлов `cxf`. После добавления:

```
cxf-api-2.2.10.jar
cxf-common-schemas-2.2.10.jar
cxf-common-utilities-2.2.10.jar
cxf-rt-bindings-soap-2.2.10.jar
cxf-rt-bindings-xml-2.2.10.jar
cxf-rt-core-2.2.10.jar
cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-2.2.10.jar
cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-2.2.10.jar
cxf-rt-frontend-simple-2.2.10.jar
cxf-rt-transports-http-2.2.10.jar
cxf-rt-ws-addr-2.2.10.jar
cxf-tools-common-2.2.10.jar
```

Все заработало!

---

Ответ из комментария.